# Laravel many to many and sub many to many

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

i have Category model which has many to many relation with user
while user model has many to many relation with area
and area has one to many relation with city
i get data of categories with user by

```
$categories = Category::where('id',$id)->with('users')->get();
```

but i don't know how to get users with area and city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just chain the eager loading

```
$categories = Category::where('id',$id)->with('users.areas.city')->get();
```

if you only need the user list, better start with that model

```
$users = User::with('areas.city')
    ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('id', $id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you ... but how to access it in blade file ?

Comment: @Hossam via the relation `$users[0]->areas[0]->city` or loop them